# How to open PDF from URL without Google doc or Google drive

Tags: android, pdf, webview, google-docs

I am new in android.

I am trying to open PDF from url in webview. Its working fine for small PDF but if i receive large PDF  from server, Then it give error,

**(No Preview Available).**

I want to show pdf from server only in view mode and user should not download and also need to clear cache after back press. Below are the code which i am using to open the PDF from server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6gdu.png)

Code:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

webview.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfUrl);
```

Answer (score 4):

use this

```
private String showPdf(String url) {
     String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=";
     return googleDocsUrl+Uri.encode(url);
}
```

if its still not available, it maybe the url is on private server.

Comment: Thank You for you reply. But still i am getting same error. Please check attached screen shot. My PDF around 40-50 pages.

Answer (score 2):

```
void showWebView(){ 
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + your_url+ "&embedded=true");
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onUnhandledKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent ke) {

        Log.e("Unhandled Key Event", ke.toString());
        //mProg.cancel();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        //mProg.cancel();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        wv_webview_content.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-GSQQnc-LgbsSe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-to915-LgbsSe VIpgJd-TzA9Ye-eEGnhe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-LgbsSe')[0].style.display='none'; })()");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://sherlock-holm.es/stories/pdf/a4/1-sided/advs.pdf");
```

replace this url https://sherlock-holm.es/stories/pdf/a4/1-sided/advs.pdf with your url. if still not work then check your pdf.

Comment: Thank You for you reply. But still i am getting same error. Please check attached screen shot. My PDF around 40-50 pages.

Comment: That format of URL doesn't seem to work now. Try
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://sherlock-holm.es/stories/pdf/a4/1-sided/advs.pdf